# Oracle rownum < [n] alternatives? Understanding Of?

Tags: sql, oracle

From my understanding, rownum is applied to the entire result set after it has been queried. This means if I wanted to limit results using rownum, it would still query everything at first. I have a user table that has over a hundred thousand records. I also am developing a site that searches this table bringing back a result set. Unfortunately, the requester wants me to include the ability to search on JUST the last name.

Imagine the about of "jones", "whites", "browns" that could come back. I would like to bring back no more than 200 records, is there a better way to do this instead of using rownum? Is my understanding on when rownum is applied correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   lastname = 'Jones'
        ORDER BY
                id
        )
WHERE   rownum <= 200
```

or

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   lastname = 'Jones'
        )
WHERE   rn <= 200
```

The latter was slower in `9i` but works just the same in `10g+`.

> From my understanding, rownum is applied to the entire result set after it has been queried

No. The `rownum` is applied as soon as each record satisfying the `WHERE` clause is fetched (but before they are ordered).

Actually, the nested query is required here because `ROWNUM` is evaluated before the `ORDER BY`.

Both `ROWNUM` and `ROW_NUMBER()` are subject to optimization.  If you have an index on `(lastname, id)`, the query will use the index and stop after returning the 200th record (you will see a `COUNT(STOPKEY)` in the plan).

Also there is a common caveat with `ROWNUM` and paging. This query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   lastname = 'Jones'
        ORDER BY
                id
        )
WHERE   rownum BETWEEN 201 AND 400
```

will never return anything, because `ROWNUM` is itself a part of the `WHERE` condition. The engine just cannot return the first row because it would have `ROWNUM = 1` which does not satisfy the `WHERE` clause.

To work around this, you would have to double-nest the query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  q.*, ROWNUM AS rn
        FROM    (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    mytable
                WHERE   lastname = 'Jones'
                ORDER BY
                        id
                ) q
        )
WHERE   rn BETWEEN 201 AND 400
```

This will be optimized to a `COUNT(STOPKEY)` too.